# ImageMagickをつかってサイズの変更したのですが、色空間が勝手にgrayになってしまう

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagickのconvertコマンドを使ってリサイズを実行したのですが、
色空間がgrayに変換されてしまいます。(入力ファイルの色空間はRGB)

```
convert img001.png -resize 532x366! img_resize001.png
```

入力ファイル
[image: 入力ファイル]

出力ファイル
[image: 出力ファイル]

そこで-colorspaceを指定して入出力ともにRGBを指定したのですが、それでも出力ファイルの色空間はgrayになってしいます。

```
convert img005.png -colorspace RGB -resize 532x366! -colorspace RGB img_resize005.png
```

なにか他に指定/設定が必要なのでしょうか？
もし、お分かりになられる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示をお願い致します。

```
※ImageMagickのバージョン情報はこちらです
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-5 Q16 x86_64 2014-07-25        
http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png xml zlib
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[このImageMagickのフォーラムの投稿](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22654&p=94555&hilit=sRGB+png#p94555)が関係ありそうです。

コマンドで、出力ファイル名の前に`PNG00:`を追加してみたらどうでしょうか？

```
convert img001.png -resize 532x366! PNG00:img_resize001.png
```

`PNG00`でうまく行かない場合は、`PNG24`で試してみてください。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。
おお、こちらにフォーラムに情報があったのですね...。
ご教示頂いたとおり、`PNG00:`を追加したところうまくいけました！
※`PNG24`でもうまくいきました。
本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます...！